# Real time Venue push "Your app can't see pushes from that venue"

Tags: foursquare

I'm working with real time venue API for some customers.
I am the owner of the app, the user is a Brand page and has authorized the app, the Brand page is manager of the venues.
I don't know why some apps work fine and some others don't work.
All looks like identical among the apps, but with some of them I get a message "Your app can't see pushes from that venue" while the test push works fine.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you were able to find an answer. I'll be writing how I solved mine.

I was having trouble on understanding why "Your app can't see pushes from that venue" was appearing even though I've been connecting the user and receiving an access token.

For venue managers, there are actually two accounts in one. First is the manager, and the second is a personal account.

When registering for app, I've been using the manager. Though the venue list api was answering with a full list, real time push was not sending any test for any venues.

Then I tried to register with the personal app, the same venue list is received and Foursquare api began giving permission to me for testing/capturing checkins.